# MongDb C# Driver is deserialzing null values for a List member as empty

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using MongoDB with c# driver in one of the applications.
I have defined an entity as below and also defined classmaps to enforce a schema.

```
public class TestEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<SomeModel> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Also, I've defined conventions to disable serialization of empty or null arrays/lists.

```
new ConventionPack { new IgnoreIfNullConvention(true)
conventionPack.Add(new IgnoreEmptyArraysConvention());
```

Everything works as expected, but when I query the document back using c# driver like below, I get the Properties as an empty list instead of null.

```
Database.GetCollection<TestEntity>("test").Find(filter, findOptions).FirstOrDefault()
```

For example, if I have a testentity document as follows, when I query using c# driver "Properties" property is returned as empty list instead of null.

{
    "_id":ObjectId("5991be3475f14655406cd301"),
    "name": "test",
    "description": "test"
   }

I couldn't find an answer when I searched online. Hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: What is `IgnoreEmptyArraysConvention` convention you're using?

Comment: The one that's mentioned over here.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-765

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the convention `IgnoreEmptyArraysConvention` looking at the code [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-765?focusedCommentId=1424700&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-1424700) it seems that it creates a new instance of a list.

Comment: yep, there it is. I haven't paid much attention to it, assuming that it would only affect the serialization, not the de-serialization. One of the side-effects of copying the code I guess. Thanks anyway !